# Calling Update Procedure in WPF?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have an `Update` stored procedure in SQL Server, and I'm calling it from my WPF application, but I want only the field to update that I give (my procedure updates 4 columns).

When you exec it in SQL with NULL behind the fields you don't want to update, it works. So is it possible to give my textboxes a NULL value so then it will see it as a NULL value?

My `Update` stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InfoUpdate] 
    (@ID int, 
     @name varchar(20) = NULL, 
     @surname varchar(20) = NULL, 
     @city varchar(20) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    UPDATE dbo.Information
    SET Name = ISNULL(@name, Name),
        Surname= ISNULL(@surname, Surname),
        City= ISNULL(@city, City)
    WHERE ID = @ID 
END
```

When I exec it:

```
exec dbo.InfoUpdate
         @ID = 1,
         @name = XXX,
         @surname = NULL,
         @city = NULL
```

It works, it keeps the old data and just updates the column I want to.

But when you do this from WPF, it makes the column blank that open.

Can I give my textbox a `NULL` value maybe?

My WPF code:

```
 // Connection to database
 string cs = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TESTSECTION;Integrated Security=True";

 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = cs;

 string x = null;

 conn.Open();

 SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("dbo.InfoUpdate", conn);
 sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID.Text;
 sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.Text;
 sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Surname.Text;
 sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = City.Text;
 sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
 conn.Close();

 conn.Open();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
 da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Information", conn);
 da.Fill(dt);

 DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
 conn.Close();
```

MY error starts here:

```
DBNull.Value : Name.Text;
```

Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

Comment: Your question would be a lot more clear if you add to it your code

Comment: I see your update, but this is not the code that I was looking for. I mean the WPF code that executes the update taking the values of your textboxes. (An hint: A TextBox.Text is never NULL, it is just an empty string) This is what happen to your columns. If you leave the textboxes blank the fields will be set to an empty string. So you need to change something in the code that updates the fields from your WPF app.

Comment: How can I make my TextBox NULL then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in comments above, you can't have a TextBox.Text set to NULL. If you try to do it nothing happens and when you read it back you get again an empty string.

However you can set your parameters to [DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) when your textboxes are empty (or whitespace)

```
sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Name.Text;
sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Surname.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Surname.Text;
sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(City.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)City.Text;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your edit. Do you have an error? If yes what is the error message? Can you write here adding a comment?

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

Comment: Just put cast in front of dbnull - `(object)DBNull.Value`

Comment: wait it works, I made a typo.. Thank you !! Steve your a great help!